# mySQL: group periodically

Tags: mysql

I have a table with prices and timestamps all 10 minutes. I'd like to get for each day the minimum price of the last 5 days. I guess I need to self join the table, but how to form the ON clause and GROUP clause?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the code that you have written so far, and explain where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Query:

```
SELECT DAY(timestampCol), MIN(price)
FROM table
GROUP BY DAY(timestampCol)
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Not really. I need to group the prices within the 5 days. In my count(prices) I get too many. `SELECT
b.pair, date(b.timestamp), count(a.price) from b
left join a
on  b.pair = a.pair
and TO_DAYS(CAST(b.timestamp AS DATE)) - TO_DAYS(CAST(a.timestamp AS DATE)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4
group by b.pair, date(b.timestamp)`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    MIN(Price) AS minPrice,
    DATE(ColTimestamp) AS thatDay,
    someProduct
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATE(ColTimestamp) > (SUBDATE(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY someProduct,
         DATE(ColTimestamp);
```